# Executar Selenium webdriver navegador oculto em Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Estou começando a programar com python3, mas estou com uma dificuldade, no qual não sei como deixar oculta a janela do navegador (firefox) oculta enquanto o código é executado.
Segue abaixo a parte que estou com dificuldade.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Eduardo\Desktop\geckodriver.exe")

driver.get("URL")
```

Comment: Habilite o modo headless no webdriver: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Firefox/Options.html#headless!-instance_method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar o parâmetro *headless* como True.

Tente isto:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, 
executable_path=r"C:\Users\Eduardo\Desktop\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("http://google.com/")
print("Modo Headless inicializado")
driver.quit()
```